# Number sequence. Replace the "?'s"

Tags: pattern, number-sequence

Replace the question marks.

6, 35, 143, ?, ?, 1147

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is:

> 323, 667

because:

> The numbers are products of consecutive primes:
>  2*3, 5*7, 11*13, 17*19, 23*29, 31*37